# Order of an element in $\Bbb{Z}_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

**Claim.** Suppose $a \in \Bbb{Z}^{\ast}_n$. If $\text{ord}_n(a) = n-1$, then $n$ is prime.

**Proof.** By contradiction, suppose $n$ is composite. Then $n=ab$, for $a,b \notin \{1,n\}$. It follows that $\phi(n) \le n-2$ (because $a$ and $b$ are not coprime with $n$) and that's false because the order of any element in a group cannot exceed the order of the group (i.e. $n-1$ $\not\le$ $\phi(n)$).

Take a look and let me know if something is missing.

Comment: OK, but I would say just a little more about the inequality for $\varphi(n)$. Such as, *$0$ and $0 < a < n$ are not coprime to $n$, hence...*

Comment: Looks okay in principle. I would not accept your "clearly it follows" just like that, though. Secondly I would rather say that the order of an element of a group ($n-1$) cannot exceed the order of the group ($\phi(n)\leq n-2$).

Comment: Got it, thanks guys!

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ does not consist of $1,2,\ldots ,n$, but rhather of $\overline{1},\ldots ,\overline{n}$, modulo $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using the definition of prime is clearer.

If $ord_n(a) = n-1$, then $1,a,a^2,\dots,a^{n-1} \bmod n$ are all different and coprime with $n$. Therefore, all numbers $1,2,\dots,n-1$ are coprime with $n$. In particular, no number among $2,\dots,n-1$ divides $n$. Therefore, $n$ is prime.